# Is there a solution for integrating the tt_news AMENU into my existing HMENU?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tt-news

My menu structure should be in this format

PressRelease (in the page tree) 
 Archive (in the page tree) 
   - Press releases 2012 (from the tt_news archive) 
   - Press releases 2011 (from the tt_news archive)

This is my HMENU

```
    lib.sidebarmenu = COA
    lib.sidebarmenu {
    10 = HMENU
    10 {
        entryLevel = 1
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
           expAll = 1
           noBlur = 1
           stdWrap.cObject = COA
           stdWrap.cObject {
           10 = HMENU
           10 {
              special = rootline
              special.range = 1|1
               wrap = <h2>|</h2>
               1 = TMENU
               1.NO.doNotLinkIt = 0
               }


           20 = HMENU
           20 {
                entryLevel = 1
                1 = TMENU
                1 {
                  expAll = 1
                  noBlur = 1
                  NO {            
                     ATagTitle.field = subtitle//title
                     ATagParams = class="sidebarNav"
                     stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1 
                     wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>      
                      }
                   ACT = 1
                   ACT {
                        wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active"> | </li>

                       }

                   }
                   2 < .1
                   2.wrap = <ul id="submenu">|</ul>
                   3 < .2
                   4 < .2
                 }
             }
            wrap =  <ul class="tabs"> | </ul>
            NO {   

          }

        }

      }

    }
 This is my AMENU

  [PIDinRootline = 55]
  lib.newsArchiveMenu < plugin.tt_news
  lib.newsArchiveMenu {
    code >
    code = AMENU
    pid_list >
    pid_list = 42,61,63
    singlePid = 44
    archiveTypoLink.parameter =55
    catImageMode = 0
    catTextMode = 0
    archiveMode = year
    archiveTitleCObject {
            10 = TEXT
            10.field = start
            10.strftime =%Y
             }
     }
```

Comment: BTW it seems that you have missing brackets and trying to nest HMENU (20) in other HMENU (10), try to clarify that first

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just put your `tt_news` menu as next element of COA object (probably just before the end of `[PIDinRootline = 55]` condition:

```
lib.sidebarmenu.30 < lib.newsArchiveMenu
```